# Connection Factory HTTPS

Tags: java, blackberry, https

Does anyone have a clue as to why this returns a null descriptor in BlackBerry OS 7?  It works fine in 5.0 and 6.0, but refuses to work with https urls.  Regular http works ok, but for some reason this fails.  I tried other similar http/https counter parts and they all have the same results.  I'm using the 9930 7.0 simulator.  I have no more hair to pull out.

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
ConnectionDescriptor descriptor = factory.getConnection("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working on this for a million years, and the moment I cave and make a question, I figured it out.  It appears the default settings on the 7.0 Simulator need to be changed.  This is what I did:

Manage Connections -> 
Under "Options and Status"... Wi-Fi Network ->
Select "Default WLAN Network"

It was peculiar because I was able to browse the net with the built in browser and the default settings.  I didn't suspect anything was out of wack.  Sigh.

Comment: If you're looking for **Manage Connections**, like I was, you'll find it under the _Home Screen_ if you choose the BB Menu and select **'Show All'**.

Comment: why it will not work unless its connected to wifi?, i'm having the same problem and i can't make it work on 3G , i did this configuration: `int[] transportTypes = {TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_MDS, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR, TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP2};`